# Which two integers produce random infinite sequence when the largest divided by the smallest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Which two integers produce random infinite sequence when the larger one is divided by the smaller one?

For instance, 
$\frac{920}{33}= 27.8787878787...$, is not a random sequence.

Comment: None. Any such number will repeat itself after at most the denominator number of digit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***No*** $2$ such integers exist , as the ratio of any $2$ integers is a **rational number** and the decimal representation of any rational number is **never** a non-recurring decimal.

Any rational number with a fractional part can be expressed to have either a finite decimal part (*with all zeroes from a certain digit onward*) or a recurring decimal part.